# My project isn't working ! causes error like this

Tags: request

> Notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\emovie24\index.php on line 7

[image: this is my index php code image]

Comment: Could you please put the code in your post instead of an image. This makes answering a lot easier. I also assume this file is called `index.php`? On a sidenote, are you sure you have a querystring parameter called `msg` in your call to this page? Some more details on how you this script might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

use the `isset` method when you are not sure about a value. In your example, `$_REQUEST['msg']` is not defined, hence the error.

You can use this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && $_REQUEST['msg'] == "reg"){
   echo "...";
}
```

which first checks that the value exists/is defined before doing any comparison.